# Dynamic range in sum formula with constraints

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to sum up some data within the current month but only until the current date.

The sheet looks something like this:

[image]

So there are 2 things to consider:

- I'd like to not use the static formula `=SUM(B32:B59)` to sum up all values from february but rather have some kind of dynamic formula which automatically sets the ranges of the `SUM` to the first & last date of the month in which the sum formula "resides".
- The end of the sum range should be constrained to not exceed the current date

Is this possible at all and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: So you just want the sum up to where you have marked <<today, which would be 91? Do you get <<today using the today() function, i.e. it would be 17/04/2015 at time of writing, or is it a past date stored in the spreadsheet somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it with a non-array formula in C59:-

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(YEAR(A59),MONTH(A59),1),A:A,"<="&A59,A:A,"<="&TODAY())
```

assuming that the first column contains a date.

Comment: One minor thing: The function parameters need to be seperated by `;` instead of `,`

Answer (score 0):

An array formula is an excellent way to combine criteria and a summary function.  You can combine several criteria by multiplying their results together.  The final result will be a 0 or 1 depending on whether or not the criteria were met.  You can then take that result, multiply by the data and `SUM`.

Here is an example that applies your conditions to some sample date.  This needs to be entered as an array formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.  It also requires that your dates really be dates and not a string.  Formula for cell `D32`.  You can copy/paste this to each end of month row.  It will give the same answer for any cell in the month though.

```
=SUM((MONTH($B$2:$B$37)=MONTH(B32))*($B$2:$B$37<TODAY())*$C$2:$C$37)
```

The image shows cell `D17` expanded.  I did this so that you can see that the results for April are correct.

[image: image of sample data]

The formula works with two conditions:

- Check that the month is the same month as the current data point
- Check that the date is less than current date